# Kendo PanelBar Not Registered

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I Used KendoPanelBar in 2 projects. In firstOne, I dont have any problem with executing , but in second one there is an Error in Firebug when I want to Run:
Error is

**kendoPanelBar is not a function**

by the way: its a very simple code

```
   $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
         expandMode: "single"
   });
```

when in firebug I check for .js files there are these files:

- kendo.web.min.js
- kendo.all.min.js
- angular.min.js
- jQuery-1.10.1.min.js

they are the same in both pages, but why this Error is happenning??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not import both of these:

- kendo.web.min.js
- kendo.all.min.js

`all` includes everything in `web`, `mobile`, and `dataviz`.
Also make sure you import Kendo *after* jQuery.

Comment: In addition make sure that you include first `jQuery`and then `kendo.*.min.js`